# Spring Boot: How to send an object to RestController from another Controller?

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest, spring-mvc

I have the method in my RestController, that accepts an object:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/statistic")
public class MyController {

    @Autowired
    private StatisticService statistic;

    @RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.POST, value="/add")
    public ResponseEntity<String> add(@RequestBody PersonData personData) {
        if(statistic.addToStatistic(personData)) {
            return new ResponseEntity<String>(HttpStatus.OK);
        }
        return new ResponseEntity<String>("Person already exists", HttpStatus.CONFLICT);
    }
}
```

I want to send the object from my another Controller. I only read, that I can send the object to /statistic/add as json via different browser tools (REST clients). But my another controller accepts only "login" (unique name) and it should create the object from this login and send to /statistic/add. Like this I wanted to create json object and send it, but I get the error
`org.springframework.web.client.RestClientException: No HttpMessageConverter for org.codehaus.jettison.json.JSONObject`
Here is my attempt:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/main")
public class ViewController {
    @RequestMapping(value = "/newPerson/{login}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @ResponseBody
    public ResponseEntity<String> registerNewPerson(@PathVariable String login) {
        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
        try {
            String uri_create = "http://localhost:8082/add/";
            //creation of json doesnt't help
            JSONObject entity = new JSONObject();
            entity.put("login", login);
            entity.put("points", 0);
            ResponseEntity<String> responce = restTemplate.postForEntity(uri_create, entity, String.class);
            return responce;
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `add(..)` requires a `PersonData` which apparently doesn't match the JSONObject built in the `registerNewPerson(...)` method.  It's unusual for a controller to call another controller.  In general, a controller should delegate to a service(s) to do it's work, and multiple controllers can share service(s).

Comment: @AndrewS could you please post an example explanation for this case?

Comment: Inject/autowire `StatisticService statistic` into `ViewController` (same as `MyController`), and invoke `StatisticService` methods directly from the `registerNewPerson(...)` method.

Comment: @AndrewS thank you for your responce. But these two controllers are in different projects, so StatisticService is in the project with MyController, and ViewController is in the other project. It's like different microservices. I guess it's impossible to inject here the service. Or should it then better be one microservice with 2 controllers?

Comment: _Or should it then better be one microservice with 2 controllers?_  It depends on the scope of each service.  For example, the two methods appear to be related to user identity.

Comment: @AndrewS my idea was to make ```ViewController``` as the main controller, it should accept different requests from client side and build ```ModelAndView``` in methods. And ```MyController``` works only with users data, like create new user, get user info, delete user.. That's why I decided to separate them